# How to handle mapped elements individually by a button of each created while mapping array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

I have created a carousel which is a column of ten dates ,for this i am mapping dates by momentjs, Inside each of this column , i am mapping different time slots for morning ,afternoon and evening,
and i have a functionality that only shows first two time slots and then there is a show more button, by clicking on this button more time slots are appear,but whenver i am clicking on this button all of the columns time slots is appearing, i have to handle all the column button individually..
Thank You in adavance... :)

below is my code...

```
 const [showMoreClicked, setShowMoreClicked] = useState(false);
  const [showMoreAfternoon, setShowMoreAfternoon] = useState(false);
  const [showMoreEvening, setShowMoreEvening] = useState(false);

  const showMoreSlotsForMorning = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setMoreClicked(!showMoreClicked);
  };

  const showMoreSlotsForAfternoon = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setShowMoreAfternoon(!showMoreAfternoon);
  };

  const showMoreSlotsForEvening = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setShowMoreEvening(!showMoreEvening);
  };







   <Carousel responsive={responsive}>
                  {nexttendates.map((elem, dateIndex) => {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        <button key={dateIndex} className="nexttendates">
                          {elem}
                        </button>
                        <div className="appointment-timelots">
                          <div className="availableslots">
                            <div className="availableslot">
                              <img
                                src="../elements/doctorlist/doctorcard/sunrise.png"
                                alt=""
                                className="sunrise"
                              />
                              Morning
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        {morningtime.map((elem, morInd, arr) => {
                          if (showMoreClicked == false) {
                            while (morInd == 0 || morInd == 1)
                              return (
                                <button key={morInd} className="appointtimes">
                                  {elem}
                                </button>
                              );
                          } else {
                            return (
                              <button key={morInd} className="appointtimes">
                                {elem}
                              </button>
                            );
                          }
                        })}
                        <button
                          choseIndex={dateIndex}
                          onClick={showMoreSlotsForMorning}
                          className="appointtimes"
                        >
                          {showMoreClicked ? "Show Less" : "Show More"}
                        </button>
                        <img
                          src="../elements/doctorlist/doctorcard/sun.png"
                          alt=""
                          className="afternoon"
                        />
                        Afternoon
                        {afternoontime.map((elem, aftInd) => {
                          if (showMoreAfternoon == false) {
                            while (aftInd == 0 || aftInd == 1)
                              return (
                                <button className="appointtimes">{elem}</button>
                              );
                          } else {
                            return (
                              <button className="appointtimes">{elem}</button>
                            );
                          }
                        })}
                        <button
                          choseIndex={dateIndex}
                          onClick={showMoreSlotsForAfternoon}
                          className="appointtimes"
                        >
                          {showMoreAfternoon ? "Show Less" : "Show More"}
                        </button>
                        <img
                          src="../elements/doctorlist/doctorcard/night-mode.png"
                          alt=""
                          className="evening"
                        />
                        Evening
                        {eveningtime.map((elem, eveInd) => {
                          if (showMoreEvening == false) {
                            while (eveInd == 0 || eveInd == 1) {
                              return (
                                <button className="appointtimes">{elem}</button>
                              );
                            }
                          } else {
                            return (
                              <button className="appointtimes">{elem}</button>
                            );
                          }
                        })}
                        <button
                          choseIndex={dateIndex}
                          onClick={showMoreSlotsForEvening}
                          className="appointtimes"
                        >
                          {showMoreEvening ? "Show Less" : "Show More"}
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
                </Carousel>


i think its happening because of i have mapped an array and only used one useState to check open or not...Can anybody plz help me....
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the time slots list as a separate component, so that each of the morning, afternoon, and evening list will have their own state automatically for toggling display.

Something like this example:

```
import { useState } from "react";

// Toggle showMore value on click

const SlotsList = ({ slots }) => {
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);

  const handleShowMoreClick = () => {
    setShowMore((prev) => !prev);
  };

// Filter the slots prop before map it if showMore is false

  return (
    <div>
      {slots
        .filter((elem, index) => (showMore ? true : index <= 1))
        .map((elem, index) => (
          <button key={index} className="appointtimes">
            {elem}
          </button>
        ))}
      <button onClick={handleShowMoreClick} className="appointtimes">
        {showMore ? "Show Less" : "Show More"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SlotsList;
```

In this example, the list is filtered before being mapped out for an easier solution. The key property should be replaced by a unique ID to avoid conflict.

It can then be imported and used like below in the main component. Also reusable for all 3 lists, and each have separate display toggle.

```
<SlotsList slots={morningtime} />
```